# How to merge two sorted arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a third sorted array, c, from the two previously created arrays, a and b; however, I'm getting several errors within the merge method that say "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to OrdArray". I've been at it for hours already, and feel like my brain is mush now. Can someone help me out?

```
class OrdArray
{
    private long[] a;                 // ref to array a 
    private int nElems;               // number of data items
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    public OrdArray(int max)          // constructor
    {
        a = new long[max];             // create array a  
        nElems = 0;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    public int size()
    { return nElems; }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    public int find(long searchKey)
    {
        int lowerBound = 0;
        int upperBound = nElems-1;
        int curIn;

        while (true)
        {
            curIn = (lowerBound + upperBound ) / 2;
            if (a[curIn] == searchKey)
                return curIn;              // found it
            else if (lowerBound > upperBound)
                return nElems;             // can't find it
            else                          // divide range
            {
                if (a[curIn] < searchKey)
                    lowerBound = curIn + 1; // it's in upper half
                else
                    upperBound = curIn - 1; // it's in lower half
            }  // end else divide range
        }  // end while

    }  // end find()
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    public void insert(long value)    // put element into array
    {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++)        // find where it goes
        if (a[j] > value)            // (linear search)
            break;
        for (int k = nElems; k > j; k--)    // move bigger ones up
            a[k] = a[k-1];
        a[j] = value;                  // insert it
        nElems++;                      // increment size
    }  // end insert()
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    public boolean delete(long value)
    {
        int j = find(value);
        if (j == nElems)                  // can't find it
            return false;
        else                           // found it
        {
            for (int k = j; k < nElems; k++) // move bigger ones down
                a[k] = a[k+1];
            nElems--;                   // decrement size
            return true;
        }
    }  // end delete()
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    public void display()             // displays array contents
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nElems; j++)       // for each element,
            System.out.print(a[j] + " ");  // display it
        System.out.println("");
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    public static long[] merge(OrdArray a, OrdArray b) 
    {

    long[] c = new long[a.nElems + b.nElems];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < a.nElems && j < b.nElems)
    {
        if (a.data[i] < b.data[j])     
            c[k++] = a.data[i++]; 
        else        
            c[k++] = b.data[j++];              
    }

    while (i < a.nElems)  
        c[k++] = a.data[i++];      

    while (j < b.nElems)    
        c[k++] = b.data[j++]; 
    return c;
    }
    }  // end class OrdArray
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  class OrderedApp
  {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
      int maxSize = 100;             // array size
      OrdArray a, b, c;                  // reference to array
      a = new OrdArray(maxSize);   // create the array
      b = new OrdArray(maxSize);
      c = new OrdArray(maxSize);

      a.insert(11);
      a.insert(13);
      a.insert(15);
      a.insert(17);
      a.insert(19);
      a.insert(21);
      a.insert(23);
      a.insert(25);
      a.insert(27);
      a.insert(29);

      b.insert(12);
      b.insert(14);
      b.insert(16);
      b.insert(18);
      b.insert(20);
      b.insert(32);
      b.insert(24);
      b.insert(26);
      b.insert(28);
      b.insert(30);

      OrdArray.merge(a,b);

      System.out.print("Array a: ");
      a.display();
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("Array b: ");
      b.display();
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("Array c: ");
      c.display();
      System.out.println();
      }  // end main()
  }// end class OrderedApp
```

Comment: Could you please mark the line(s) where you got the error?  (Edit the source and put a comment on the problem line(s).  Don't tell us the line number included in the error message, because we won't be able to figure out which line that is.)

Comment: It's been fixed. Sorry about that.

Comment: read the last part of mergesort

Comment: Hi @Rainwater. My aproach looks similar to yours. Are you preparing from Robert Lafore's book? See my answer. Thanks.

I am confused why you are using binary search. Simple way is to insert two arrays using two insert methods or one. Using a merge method, just merge those two already sorted arrays by comparing the least element among two sorted arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrdArray` is not an array type (despite the name); therefore, you can't index it like an array.  This expression

```
a[i++]
```

where `a` is an `OrdArray`, will have no meaning.  Java doesn't give you a way to define your own `[]` operator for classes (unlike C++).  Therefore, you'll have to add a method to `OrdArray` to return the element at a given index, something like

```
public long get(int index) { ...write the code... }

a.get(i++) // will then get the element at that index
```

Although I'm not sure this is what you want, since you've declared `c` to be an `int[]` and the array in `OrdArray` to be a `long[]`, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

**EDIT:** After reading your comment, I realized that the `merge` method is inside the `OrdArray` class.  I missed that before.  Since that's the case, you don't need to add a `get` method; you can access the private fields of your `OrdArray` parameters directly.  In your method:

```
public void merge(OrdArray a, OrdArray b)
```

you want to get at the private array `a` that you declare for each `OrdArray`.  If you just use `a`, the variable will refer to the `OrdArray`, which isn't an array (as described above); to get at the `long[] a` belonging to the `OrdArray a`, you need to say

```
a.a[i++]
```

and likewise, for `b`,

```
b.a[i++]
```

This can look confusing to a reader, so I suggest coming up with a better name so that you're not calling two things `a`.  Perhaps `data`?

A couple other things: You use `merge` like this: `c.merge(a,b)`, which means that `merge` is an instance method and `c` is the instance you're operating on.  But your method doesn't do anything with the current instance.  (The `c` you declare in `merge` is a local variable that has nothing to do with the `c` you use when calling `merge`.)  Right now, your method is going to a lot of trouble to construct the local array `c`, but then it just throws it away.  You either need to (1) fix the method so that it sets up the `a` (or `data`) array in the current instance; or (2) make it a `static` method and make the method return the new array as a function result.  I'm not sure which one your instructor wants you to do.

Comment: c should actually be a `long[]`. I was tinkering around and forgot to change it back. I don't believe our instructor wanted us to make any methods other than the merge method. Your way of using `get` makes plenty of sense to me, but as I said, I don't think he wants us to do that.

Comment: I updated it with some of the changes you suggested, and I'm error free now! The problem is that it isn't returning anything for `c.display();`. I'm getting really confused with this, so please bear with me. I also changed it to `OrdArray.merge` because it suggested the fix when I changed the method to static. I'm sure that isn't right, but like I said, I'm getting rather confused at this point.

Comment: If you can't figure it out on your own, you'll probably need to post this as a new question, with the latest version of your source (hopefully trimmed dwon to the smallest piece of code that demonstrates the problem).  StackOverflow is organized in a question-and-answer format, not as a running discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do. But to resolve error, i have corrected the articular block.

To note, `OrdArray` class is not an array. It's a class that has a `long[] a`. So you need to get the array like any other property from the object.

For betterment, please change the method signature like this:

```
public void merge(OrdArray ordArr1, OrdArray ordArr2) {//Note parameters' name change
.
.
.

while (i < ordArr1.nElems && j < ordArr2.nElems)
  {
      if (ordArr1.a[i] < ordArr2.a[j])      //should resolve
          c[k++] = ordArr1.a[i++]; 
      else        
          c[k++] = ordArr2.a[j++];              
  }

  while (i < a.nElems)  
      c[k++] = ordArr1.a[i++];      

  while (j < b.nElems)    
      c[k++] = ordArr2.a[j++]; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused why you are using binary search. Simple way is to insert two arrays using two insert methods or one. Using a merge method, just merge those two already sorted arrays by comparing the least element among two sorted arrays.

> Remove delete, search etc methods, they are not required.

This is my code. I have inserted two integer arrays(elements) into inserta() and insertb() sorted them and merged them using insert() method. Finally I have this sorted array after merging them. Please see my code here:

```
    package sample;

/**
 *
 * @author Shivasai
 */
public class Merge {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int n;
    int m;
    int p;
    private long[] a;
    private long[] b;
    private long[] c;
    public Merge()
    {
        a=new long[10];
        b=new long[10];
        c=new long[100];
        n=0;
        m=0;
        p=0;
    }
    void inserta(long key)
    {
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
          if(a[i]>key)
              break;
      }
      for(j=n;j>i;j--)
      {
          a[j]=a[j-1];

      }
      a[j]=key;
      n++;

    }
    void insertb(long value)
    {
      for(i=0;i<m;i++)
      {
          if(b[i]>value)
              break;
      }
      for(j=m;j>i;j--)
      {
          b[j]=b[j-1];

      }
      b[j]=value;
      m++;

    }
    void insert()
    {
        i=0;
        j=0;

        while(i>n || j<m)
        {
            if(a[j]<b[i])
            {
                c[p]=a[j];
                j++;
            p++;
            }
            else
            {
                c[p]=b[i];
                i++;
                p++;
            }


        }



    }
    void displaya()
    {
        for(k=0;k<10;k++)
        {
            System.out.print("," +a[k]);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    void displayb()
    {
        for(k=0;k<10;k++)
        {
            System.out.print("," +b[k]);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    void displayc()
    {
        for(k=0;k<20;k++)
        {
            System.out.print("," +c[k]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Merge obj = new Merge();
        obj.inserta(25);
                                    obj.inserta(12);
                                    obj.inserta(1800);
                                    obj.inserta(9);
                                    obj.inserta(10);
                                    obj.inserta(15);
                                    obj.inserta(18);
                                    obj.inserta(19);
                                    obj.inserta(0);
                                    obj.inserta(1500);
                                    obj.insertb(36);
                                    obj.displaya();
                                    obj.insertb(2);
                                    obj.insertb(3);
                                    obj.insertb(2000);
                                    obj.insertb(5);
                                    obj.insertb(6);
                                    obj.insertb(7);
                                    obj.insertb(8);
                                    obj.insertb(21);
                                    obj.insertb(85);
                                    obj.displayb();
                                    obj.insert();
                                    obj.displayc();


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you accept solution wit Lists it would be:

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(sourceArray));
result.addAll(Arrays.asList(secondSourceArray));
Collections.sort(result);
```

You can optionally convert it back to array with

```
result.toArray();
```